Do any of the PAMGuard modules use towed array depth readings?
I am using PAMGuard to playback towed array data from DCLDE 2022 dataset. I used the array configuration dialog to import the DCLDE 2022 array file and see all 6 channels of data when I start PAMGuard processing. So far, so good! The DCLDE 2022 dataset also provided a file of periodic depth readings for the towed array so I was wondering if any of the PAMGuard modules use this data.

There are a lot of different PAMGuard modules, and PAMGuard is distributed and under active development. So it is likely that there is no single person on the planet who uses and has familiarity with all of modules out there (let alone has this familiarity and additionally reads and responds to this stack-exchange). You might be more likely to get a response if you provide more information about what it is you are trying to achieve by playing back this dataset in PAMGuard.


Do any of the PAMGuard modules use towed array depth readings?

My understanding from reading the PAMGuard's Help files is that depth data can be collected in PAMGuard via the 'Hydrophone Depth Readout' and/or 'Analog Array Sensors' modules. This information is then passed to the Array Manager, which updates the hydrophone depth.
I would guess that it is possible, if not likely, that the Target Motion Analysis localiser would make use of such information. Other modules that could potentially benefit from more accurate information on hydrophone depth include the Group 3D Localiser, and the Multipath 3D localiser.
I don't have any direct experience with any of these modules, so can't really provide a definitive answer to the question. Hopefully a useful start though.
